# How to convert n arrays of length m into m arrays of length n?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to convert this:

```
[ [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [5, 6, 7, 8],
  [9, 10, 11, 12] ]
```

into this:

```
[ [1, 5, 9],
  [2, 6, 10],
  [3, 7, 11],
  [4, 8, 12] ]
```

Is there a build-in function to do this? If it's not, what's the shorter and cleaner way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The builtin method you are looking for is [Array#transpose](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose)